# What is the equivalent in dplyr to an Excel formula referencing the cell immediately above itself?

Tags: r, excel, dplyr

In the reproducible `R` code shown at the bottom, I'm trying to create a column called `LowClassSplit`, using R package `dplyr`,  whose value depends on its own value calculated immediately above itself. My attempt to resolve is commented out. Equivalent to the Excel calculations illustrated below and highlighted yellow, where the calculations in each Column F cell refers to its value immediately above itself. The blue cells show the column F calculations using the `=FORMULATEXT(...)` formula in Excel.

Any recommendations for the functional equivalent in `dplyr`? Or if not available in `dplyr`, in base R?

Below is the expected output in R, same as the illustrated Excel example:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   Element SplitCode PreSplitClass ClassAtSplit
   <chr>       <dbl>         <int>        <dbl>
 1 C               0             1            0
 2 B               0             1            0
 3 D               0             1            0
 4 A               0             1            0
 5 A               1             2            2
 6 A               1             3            2
 7 C               0             2            0
 8 B               0             2            0
 9 B               2             3            0
10 B               2             4            0
```

[image]

Reproducible code:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    Element = c("C","B","D","A","A","A","C","B","B","B"),
    SplitCode = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,2,2)  
  )

data <- data %>% group_by(Element) %>% mutate(PreSplitClass=row_number()) %>% ungroup()

data %>%
  mutate(ClassAtSplit =
           case_when(
             SplitCode == 0 ~ as.integer(0), # This eliminates checking for > 0
             SplitCode > lag(SplitCode) ~ PreSplitClass, # if > previous value
             SplitCode == SplitCode ~ lag(PreSplitClass) # if equal (0s are avoided)
           )
  )

# Below shows where I was going before running into issue of referencing cell above:
# data %>%
#   mutate(LowClassSplit =
#            case_when(
#              SplitCode == 0 ~ as.integer(0),
#              (SplitCode == lag(SplitCode) && lagitself == 1)|(SplitCode > lag(SplitCode) & PreSplitClass == 1) ~ 1
#            )
#   )
```

**Final code including Rui Barrada's posted solution:**

```
library(dplyr)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    Element = c("C","B","D","A","A","A","C","B","B","B"),
    SplitCode = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,2,2)  
  )

excelCopy <- data %>% 
  group_by(Element) %>% 
  mutate(PreSplitClass = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(ClassAtSplit =
           case_when(
             SplitCode == 0 ~ as.integer(0), # This eliminates checking for > 0
             SplitCode > lag(SplitCode) ~ PreSplitClass, # if > previous value
             SplitCode == lag(SplitCode) ~ lag(PreSplitClass) # if equal (0s are avoided)
           )
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    LowClassSplit =
      case_when(
        SplitCode > lag(SplitCode) & SplitCode == 1 ~ PreSplitClass,
        SplitCode == lag(SplitCode) & SplitCode == 1 ~ lag(PreSplitClass),
        TRUE ~ 0L
      )
  )
```

Comment: Start by replacing `&&` by `&` and `||` by `|`. Can you post the expected output of that last data set/pipe?

Comment: On the Excel example C1 is being used in LowClassSplit. Is that relevant? Should you be creating a variable targetClass to pull in?

Comment: In response to Rui Barrada - I just edited per your suggestion. The expected output for the LowClassSplit column in R is shown in column F, LowClassSplit. But I-ll try spelling it out more clearly in another edit.

Comment: In response to CALUM - my next step, once figuring out the question in this post, is to create a variable targetClass. Correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following is what the question is asking for.

```r
library(dplyr)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    Element = c("C","B","D","A","A","A","C","B","B","B"),
    SplitCode = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,2,2)  
  )

data <- data %>% 
  group_by(Element) %>% 
  mutate(PreSplitClass = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup()

data %>%
  mutate(
    LowClassSplit =
      case_when(
        SplitCode > lag(SplitCode) & SplitCode == 1 ~ PreSplitClass,
        SplitCode == lag(SplitCode) & SplitCode == 1 ~ lag(PreSplitClass),
        TRUE ~ 0L
      )
  )
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>    Element SplitCode PreSplitClass LowClassSplit
#>    <chr>       <dbl>         <int>         <int>
#>  1 C               0             1             0
#>  2 B               0             1             0
#>  3 D               0             1             0
#>  4 A               0             1             0
#>  5 A               1             2             2
#>  6 A               1             3             2
#>  7 C               0             2             0
#>  8 B               0             2             0
#>  9 B               2             3             0
#> 10 B               2             4             0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Rui, that is what I intended and your solution works. What does TRUE ~ 0L do in your mutate statement? For the sake of completeness I also edit the OP to include your answer for LowClassSplit while retaining the column ClassAtSplit which is needed for further calculations

Comment: @CuriousJorge-user9788072 `TRUE ~ 0L` gives the statement a default value, in case none of the other conditions is met. It is always a good idea to include a `TRUE ~ default` at the end of a `case_when` instruction.